# Changing databases

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application that integrates Entity Framework and is connected to `database1`. I created a new database that I want to use instead. How do I switch to `database2`?

I tried changing the connection string to `database2`, and ran `update-database` in the pm console, but I get an error that there are multiple `DbContext` and I need to choose one. I don't know what that means.

Comment: It means that your project contains more than one type that derives from DbContext, and it doesn't know which one you want to use.

Comment: you should change under WebConfig for MVC5 or appsetting.json if u r using .core version